# Вопрос по дженерикам метода и ограничению переменных типов

Tags: java, generics

Сейчас активно изучаю (или даже разбираю) известное пособие Хорстмена и Корнелла по Java2. В данный момент остановился на параметризации. Дошел до пункта "Обобщенные методы" и следующий за ним "Ограничения переменных типов". И в ближайшем листинге среди прочего кода появляется такая сигнатура:

```
public static <T extends Comparable> Pair<T> minmax(T[] a)
```

Я понимаю, что в методе применяется метод compareTo(), принадлежащий интерфейсу Comparable и поэтому мы должны "защитить" наш метод от того, чтобы туда не затесался класс, который не реализует данный интерфейс. Ок, понятно. Но почему бы тогда нельзя было написать:

```
public static Pair<T extends Comparable> minmax(T[] a)
```

С другой стороны, возможно имелось в виду, что это не объект класса Pair должен возвращать метод, а объект любого класса, реализующий Comparable?
Тогда почему не написать так:

```
public static <T extends Comparable> T minmax(T[] a)
```

?

Я не отрицаю, что в пособии вполне может быть указана правильная сигнатура. И если это так, то прошу подробно описать ее.
Заранее спасибо за развернутые ответы!

Comment: Перефразируйте вопрос на человеческом языке.

Comment: вроде норм теперь

Comment: @Andr Все дело в синтаксисе Java. Предложенный вами вариант некорректен. Думаю тут дело в том, что метод статический. И объявление generic типа должно быть перед определением возвращаемого типа.  На счет того, что должно быть вместо Pair<T> точно не могу ответить. Может тут опечатка, ведь должно быть Pair<T,T> или может там другая причина. Но судя по названию метода, то ищется минимально и максимальное значение в массиве, так что Pair - это нормально.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вы хотите развёрнутых ответов? Их есть у меня! Немного теории по параметризованным методам.

Если метод нестатический, а класс - параметризованный, то параметр типа наследуется из описания класса:

```
public class A<T> {
    pubic void doSth(T t) { // метод принимает аргумент типа T
        System.out.println(t.getClass().getName());
    }
}

new A<String>().doSth("abc");   // выведет java.lang.String
new A<String>().doSth(123);     // не скомпилируется
```

Если метод статический, то унаследовать параметр типа от класса он не может. Это вызвано тем, что параметр типа привязывается к конкретному объекту при его создании, а статический метод не привязан к конкретному объекту, он привязан к классу в целом. В случае статического метода параметр типа нужно указывать непосредственно перед объявлением метода:

```
public class A {
    public static <T> void doSth(T t) {
        System.out.println(t.getClass().getName());
    }
}

A.doSth("abc");         // выведет java.lang.String
A.doSth(123);           // выведет java.lang.Integer
```

В этом случае тип `T` определяется в момент вызова статического метода по типу передаваемого аргумента.

Ещё один случай, когда может понадобиться явно параметризовать метод - это нестатический метод, параметр типа которого должен отличаться от параметра типа класса:

```
public class A<T>
{
    T t;

    public A(T t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    public <Z> void doSth(Z z) {
        System.out.println(t.getClass().getName());
        System.out.println(z.getClass().getName());
    }
}

new A<String>("abc").doSth(123); // выведет java.lang.String
                                 //         java.lang.Integer
```

Если в момент компиляции вычислить тип параметра метода невозможно, необходимо явно указать его при вызове. Такие случаи очень редки, поэтому пример несколько синтетический:

```
public class A
{
    public static void printValue(String val) {
        System.out.println("String");
    }

    public static void printValue(Integer val) {
        System.out.println("Integer");
    }

    public static <T> T getValue() {
        return null;
    }
}

A.printValue(A.getValue());          // не скомпилируется - неясно, какую
                                     // перегрузку printValue вызывать
A.printValue(A.<String>getValue());  // выведет String
A.printValue(A.<Integer>getValue()); // выведет Integer
```

---

Теперь непосредственно к вашему вопросу. Нельзя просто написать

```
public static Pair<T extends Comparable> minmax(T[] a)
```

потому что Java не знает, что за тип `T`. Java не может унаследовать его от объявления класса (даже если класс параметризован), так как метод `minimax` статический. Поэтому нужно явно прописывать параметр типа в сигнатуре метода:

```
public static <T extends Comparable> Pair<T> minmax(T[] a)
```

Почему нельзя написать

```
public static <T extends Comparable> T minmax(T[] a)
```

? Можно, это корректная сигнатура метода. Однако, судя по названию метода, он должен возвращать одновременно минимальное и максимальное значение переданного массива. Поэтому метод возвращает объект класса `Pair<T>`, который содержит в себе два значения.

Comment: В общем, камнем преткновения выступил именно тот факт, что метод статический. Теперь понял. Ответ супер, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Сигнатура абсолютна верна.

Первый предложенный вами вариант исключается, потому что в статическом методе нельзя использовать типы, определенные в классе. Вам этого не позволит компилятор.

Второй вариант нелогичен, т.к. метод возвращает пару значений `(min, max)`, а для этого нужен какой-то контейнер, например `Pair`. В данном случае предполагается, что оба элемента в кортеже имеют одинаковый тип.